# ASSERT: _before() should be called while animating

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

When I navigate from my dashboard ion menu to Login screen and after successfully logged in when I am trying to open ion menu again it automatically closed and got this error.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.29
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.29
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.14.0
   native-run                             : 1.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.24.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.11
   OS     : Linux 5.4
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 Logout() {
    if (this.menuCtrl.isOpen()) {
      this.menuCtrl.close();
      this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
    }
  }
```